# What statistical test to be used to find a change in the trend of a quarterly data with 20 data points?

Tags: trend

Monetizable active Twitter users Quarterly data from 2017Q1 to 2022Q2

[image]

If I have to show that the trend was affected/increased in Q1'20, Which statistical test should I use?
I expect to see the change in Q1'20 because of the COVID lockdowns.

Comment: Make a graph. FIrst thing always should be to plot the data and inspect it with your calibrated eyeballs. ("I have to show" is a terrible beginning for an investigation.)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to test for a change at that specific quarter, you could run a regression with time as one independent variable and a dummy for being before or after Q120.

If you want to see if that is the quarter when things changed, you could run a spline regression with one knot and see if that is where the knot comes.

Answer (score 0):

Interrupted Time Series analysis (such as segmented regression) is the field of choice for this sort of problems.[More Info](https://ds4ps.org/pe4ps-textbook/docs/p-020-time-series.html#:%7E:text=Interrupted%20time%20series%20can%20be,one%20specific%20point%20in%20time.)